# Why Does R's ccf say "Autocorrelations of series 'X', by lag"?

Tags: r, cross-correlation

Executing in the R shell the cross correlation between a and b:

```
> x=ccf(a,b)
> x

Autocorrelations of series ‘X’, by lag
...
```

Why is the term "Autocorrelations" used?  I thought "autocorrelation" was the correlation of a sequence with a lagged version of itself, not with another (possibly lagged) sequence.

Comment: `ccf` is cross-correlation. If you want autocorrelation, please use `acf`.

Comment: That's fine but I want cross correlations.  ccf says its giving me "Autocorrelations" and I don't what autocorrelations. I want cross correlations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ccf` first temporally intersects the two time series, and then passes the result to `acf`. In other words, the cross-correlation is the autocorrelation of the intersected, bivariate series `X`.

This is evident when looking at the source of `ccf`, which you can do by typing `ccf` and hitting enter (alternatively, in RStudio, type it and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to open the source in a new script tab).

Here is an excerpt:

```
function (x, y, lag.max = NULL, type = c("correlation", "covariance"), 
  plot = TRUE, na.action = na.fail, ...) 
{
  ..
  X <- ts.intersect(as.ts(x), as.ts(y))
  colnames(X) <- c(deparse(substitute(x))[1L], deparse(substitute(y))[1L])
  acf.out <- acf(X, lag.max = lag.max, plot = FALSE, type = type, 
    na.action = na.action)
  ..
}
```